# Do to-infinitves have the meaning of repetition?

Tags: infinitives

> > i         a. I like to stay home at weekends. 
> >     b. I like staying home at weekends.
> >     ii         a. I’d like to be a politician.
> >                  b. I’d like being a politician.
>
> With [i] there are many contexts where [a] and [b] would be equally
>   appropriate, but there are also some favouring one or the other.
>   Suppose you ask me to go bushwalking next week-end but I wish to
>   decline: [a] would here be more appropriate than [b]. Conversely if I
>   am currently enjoying a week-end at home [b] is more appropriate than
>   [a]. 
>      The infinitival is more associated
>   with change, the gerund-participial with actuality. Thus someone who
>   has recently turned forty or got married might say *I like being forty*
>   or *I like being married*. An infinitival would be strange here,
>   suggesting repeated changes from not being forty or married to being
>   forty or married. In this case the meaning is close to that of enjoy,
>   which only allows gerund-participials. *Would like*, by contrast,
>   projects into the future and resembles a verb of wanting, with a
>   strong preference for the infinitival, as in [iia]; [iib] is possible,
>   but the interpretation is roughly “I’d like/enjoy the life of a
>   politician”. If we change the examples to *I’d like to start the
>   meeting a little earlier this week* the gerund-participial becomes
>   quite implausible: *I’d like starting the meeting a little earlier*
>   suggests that the starting is itself something to be enjoyed, which is
>   an odd idea.
>
> *Hate* with a to-infinitival has an idiomatic use seen
>   in
>
> > [53] I hate to tell you this, but your battery is flat.
>
> This can be thought of as involving projection into the immediate
>   future: “I’m going to tell you, though I hate having to do so”. What
>   is special about this use (virtually confined to the 1st person) is
>   the combination of simple present tense in the matrix and single
>   dynamic event in the complement - contrast [52ia], where we have
>   **repetition** of staying home; other verbs of liking and not liking do not
>   allow this pattern, though it is found with adjectives: *I am happy /
>   ✲like to tell you that you’ve passed your test* (cf. also *regret* in
>   [56] below).
>  (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language)

What does it mean: a to-infinitival has the meaning of repetition?

Comment: Yes, but so does the -ing form ("gerund-participial"), too. They **both** express a repeated action, *I like staying* and *I like to stay*.

Comment: But they are saying "the gerund-participial tends to suggest ongoing activity" on p1241, 5th line from bottom.

Comment: I don't quite see why that should matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is trying to illustrate the difference between *I hate to tell you this...*, where *to tell* is only a one-time event, and *I like to stay home at weekends*, where *to stay* is a repeated/habitual action.  It's saying that *I hate to tell you this* is a unique construction, because usually *I like/hate to [verb]* is an expression of a repeated/habitual choice/action/preference.