# I'm happy returning home

Tags: tense, infinitives, present-participles

1. *I'm happy **to return** home.*
2. *I'm happy **returning** home.*

What do sentences 1) and 2) mean?

a) Have I already returned home? Or,

b) Am I on my way back home? Or,

c) Will I return home soon?

Comment: Both 1 and 2 can mean a-c with more context. Things exist within context and do not have to carry all meaning inside. Planning on the return, I can say 1 and 2. Flying home, I can say 1 and 2. A week later, too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Do you like to get up early?"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11487/do-you-like-to-get-up-early)

Comment: The second is not a common construction, and gives the sense of "I'm happy *while* returning home." But to reinforce Yosef's comment: The meanings you're proposing do not come from this sentence, but from the context (like: Is the speaker actually at home when they say it?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a can of worms. There are so many different contexts that could determine a different meaning, and general parlance (everyday speech) allows for meanings that don't stand up to scrutiny by strict grammatical rules. You're probably going to get different answers to this.

To strictly analyse your examples:

- "I'm happy to return home" - *to return* suggests you haven't actually returned home yet, but you are going to and you are happy about that fact.
- "I'm happy returning home" - the present continuous 'returning' makes this sound like you are happy *while* you are making the journey home.

Yet, both of those might be said to mean you are happy *at home*, either when you are presently there, or in general. They sound a little formal for something so personal, though. Most people would say something like:

- "I'm happy *to be* home" - when you are already there.
- "I'm happy *when I go* home" - meaning you are happy *whenever* you are home.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are ambiguous.
1a) I am willing to return home. [but may not do so]
1b) I am happy that I will be going home.
1c) I am happy now that I am home. (although strictly this is "I am happy **to have returned** home")
2a) I am happy during the journey to home.
2b) I am happy that I am in the process of returning home.
The subtle difference between 2a and 2b is that in 2a you are enjoying the journey itself (but not necessarily actually being home) whilst 2b you are happy because you will be home.
Happy has two different meanings
A) To be light hearted, eager, enjoying something, not sad
B) To be willing to do something.

Your 3 options could be answered
a) I have returned home.
b) I am [currently] returning home.
c) I will return home soon.
None of them require "happy"